# Material UI React - modal data in loop is only showing the last iteration data

Tags: material-ui

I have a list of blog posts.  When you click the title of a post a modal opens up to show the entire post.  The Material UI React modal is only showing the data from the last iteration no matter which title was picked.  Shouldn't the modal data be based on the iteration of the loop?

In my example there are 3 posts.  I put the post.id to show which post the modal is for, just for testing, and all 3 posts show 3.  Not 1, 2, 3 etc.  Any help is appreciated!

```
            {blogs.map(post => (
            < Card className = { classes.root } variant = "outlined" >
            <CardContent>
                <Typography variant="h4" component="h2">
                        <span onClick={handleOpen}>{post.title}</span>
                    </Typography>
                    <Modal
                        aria-labelledby="transition-modal-title"
                        aria-describedby="transition-modal-description"
                        className={classes.modal}
                        open={open}
                        onClose={handleClose}
                        closeAfterTransition
                        BackdropComponent={Backdrop}
                        BackdropProps={{
                            timeout: 500,
                        }}
                    >
                        <Fade in={open}>
                            <div className={classes.paper}>
                                {post.id}
                            </div>
                        </Fade>
                    </Modal>
                <Typography className={classes.pos} color="textSecondary">
                    Posted: {post.published} | Author: {post.author}
                </Typography>
            </CardContent>
            </Card>
```

Comment: This shouldn't be the case. `console.log` and check if `blogs` has different ids for each posts. Also add the code of your complete `Modal` component or create a codesandbox.io to help better understand the problem.

Comment: It isn’t opening only the last one. It is opening all of the modals because they are all controlled by the same `open` variable. The last one is just the one on top.